# How to add custom decimal point validation on custom options magento

Tags: admin, custom-options, validation

How to add custom decimal point validation on custom options magento

Text field Custom options Validation :
Below are the rules for this entry. Entry is limited to numerical 1-10 and a decimal character (“.”). Please let me know if you have a better way to do this:

XXX.XXXXXX (X = numerical entry) Maximum 3 digit entry before decimal and maximum 6 digit entry after decimal. Number between 001.000000 AND 166.000000 Limit